# Decoding jwt error: Unable to decode the payload as Base64Url encoded string

Tags: c#, node.js, base64, jwt

I have a jwt token 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.YUExIQ.srnc87a8Se8arhCopLBpgxEvILA2AZxOB8BIrFDHKL4
' 
that was encode in node and I'm trying to decode it in c# but I'm getting an error thrown that it's upset about the payload.

```
    public void Consume(BasicDeliverEventArgs msg)
    {
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg.Body);
        var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(message);

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        try
        {    
            var x = handler.ReadToken(user.Password) as JwtSecurityToken;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }



        _repo.UpdateUser(user);
    }
```

returns error: Unable to decode the payload 'YUExIQ' as Base64Url encoded string

I'm not sure if theres somewhere I can put the secret that was used to encode in the decoding somewhere or if I somehow need to convert the payload the base64 or if I'm just missing some steps somewhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked about decoding using Base64, I'll focus on that issue, rather than the semantics of JWT in .NET. This should demystify JWT tokens a bit.

Note that only the first segment of your JWT string above is valid—it converts to `{"alg":"HS256"}`, while the second converts to `aA1!`—so for example’s sake, I will use the default sample value from http://jwt.io:

```
var jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ";
```

So, per [JWT.io's introduction](http://JWT.io/introduction), you have just three segments in a JWT token:

- Header
- Payload
- Signature

Assuming the token is not encrypted, the first two segments can be decoded using plain Base64 (once you pad the length to a multiple of four, as @Jacob mentioned above). The last segment is just a cryptographic signature; it does not contain any meaningful encoded information to decode.

So, a simple code snippet to display the decoded JWT contents could look like this:

```
var decoded = jwt.Split('.')
  .Take(2)
  .Select(x => 
    Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
      Convert.FromBase64String(
        x.PadRight(x.Length + (x.Length % 4), '='))))
.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + Environment.NewLine + s2);

Console.WriteLine(decoded);

/* Prints:
   {
     "alg": "HS256",
     "typ": "JWT"
   }
   {
     "sub": "1234567890",
     "name": "John Doe",
     "admin": true
   }
*/
```

A simpler example that separates all the lambdas could look like:

```
/// <summary>
/// A function to make the Base64 decoding a little less
/// verbose below:
/// </summary>
string Base64Decode(string value)
{
    return Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(value)); 
}

// Get the first two segments into an enumerable:
var pieces = jwt.Split('.').Take(2);
// Pad them with equals signs to a length that is a multiple of four:
var paddedPieces = pieces.Select(x => x.PadRight(x.Length + (x.Length % 4), '='));
// Base64 decode the pieces:
var decodedPieces = paddedPieces.Select(x => Base64Decode(x));
// Join it all back into one string with .Aggregate:
Console.WriteLine(decodedPieces.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + Environment.NewLine + s2));
```

The result here is the same as the one above.

Now of course, if you intend to do meaningful JWT operations like signing and verification, you should use the `JwtSecurityToken` class in [`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/). But if you just need to find out what information a non-encrypted token contains, it's as simple as the above.

Comment: I think this answer is not bad, but it has missed to mention, that [base64url](https://base64.guru/standards/base64url) is used for JWT. Und thus string replacements for "-" to "+" and "_" to "/" are needed.

Answer (score 2):

I can't add a comment, just want to add to @paul-smith answer.

His answer worked but theres a slight bug in the logic to pad the string to a multiple of 4.

Instead of,

```
var paddedPieces = pieces.Select(x => x.PadRight(x.Length + (x.Length % 4), '='));
```

It should be...

```
var paddedPieces = pieces.Select(x => x.PadRight(x.Length + ((x.Length % 4 != 0) ? (4 - x.Length % 4) : 0), '='));
```

You need to check "x.Length % 4 != 0" otherwise it might add "====" on the end in the cases when the string is already a multiple of 4 which breaks the Base64 decoding. But the real issue is that is should be **(4 - x.Length % 4)** not **(x.Length % 4)**

e.g.

If the string was 7 characters long...

7 + (7 % 4) = 10
7 + (4 - (7 % 4) = 8

Answer (score 0):

With JWT, you omit the padding bytes. .NET requires the padding `=` characters at the end in order to make the number of characters a multiple of 4. `YUExIQ==` should be decodable.

Comment: You need to add the padding to each of the dot-separated parts separately. The `=` characters are not valid in the JWT, but when it's being parsed, you'll have to add them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean because the ReadToken takes in a single string param. You want me to split(.) and add the = padding and then join them together?

Comment: I think the error is inside the methods you're calling, not in the code you posted. Is this a third-party library?