# GetFromJsonAsync system.text.json error when returning jwt as string from api

Tags: c#, jwt, blazor-webassembly

I have this:

```
token = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<string?>($"api/account/login/{user}/{pass}");
```

and the api returns this string (a jwt):

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhbGkiLCJqdGkiOiIyMmRjZjY4MS0wNzgyLTQzYzQtODBhNy1hMjk4MjZkYjNkM2IiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1laWRlbnRpZmllciI6IjEyMzQiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiYWxpIiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS93cy8yMDA4LzA2L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9yb2xlIjpbIkVkaXRvcnMiLCJVc2VycyJdLCJleHAiOjE3MDA2ODgyNDYsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjcyMDEvIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NzIwMS8ifQ.U7tjYmnibNgLs42egibt8zypaorteE0UafunagIk-ao
```

But I get the error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: 'e' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'e' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'e' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ContinueDeserialize(ReadBufferState& bufferState, JsonReaderState& jsonReaderState, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.<DeserializeAsync>d__1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<<FromJsonAsyncCore>g__Core|12_0>d`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51]].MoveNext()
   at OTS.UI.Client.FetchData.FetchData.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\Users\mazia\Desktop\UI\OTS.UI.Client\FetchData\FetchData.razor:line 50
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Your returned string is not a JSON string literal (it's missing the surrounding quotes) so cannot be deserialized with System.Text.Json or any other JSON serializer in C# / .NET.  [How to decode JWT Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38340078) or [Decoding jwt error: Unable to decode the payload as Base64Url encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43074897) might be relevant to you though.  Or maybe you just need to call [`GetStringAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync) and go from there?